# How to use a WPF-Combo-Box with fluent nHibernate so its saves after the user changes the selection?

Tags: wpf, combobox, fluent-nhibernate

This is my ComboBox:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="comboBoxExchange" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="167,162,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="222" SelectedItem="{Binding Exchange}"/>
```

This is the code I use to initialize the ComboBox:

```
private void InitExchange()
{
    comboBoxExchange.ItemsSource = (from p in m_DbSession.Query<Exchange>() orderby p.Name select p);
    comboBoxExchange.DisplayMemberPath = "Name";
    comboBoxExchange.SelectionChanged += comboBoxExchange_SelectionChanged;
}
```

So I want to save my data after the user changes the selection with this function:

```
private void Save()
{
    using (var transaction = m_DbSession.BeginTransaction())
    {
        m_DbSession.SaveOrUpdate(m_DBProduct);
        transaction.Commit();
    }
}
```

The problem is that I cant find the event that works with this.

- SelectionChanged is fired when the window is loaded without the user doing anything
- LostFocus is fired multible times even when the user just "opens" the combobox and closes it without changing anything.

Comment: can be done without using ComboBox events. there is binding `SelectedItem="{Binding Exchange}"` - so track changes of Exchange property

Answer (score 1):

> SelectionChanged is fired when the window is loaded without the user doing anything

Yes, but you could return from the event handler immediately the first time using the `IsLoaded` property:

```
private void comboBoxExchange_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsLoaded)
        return;

    //your code to be executed when the user actually selects an item...
}
```

So `SelectionChanged` is the event to handle here.

Alternatively, you could implement kick-off your logic in the setter of the `Exchange` source property.